# Photoshop Text Layer is Locked and I did not Lock it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers

In Adobe Photoshop 7 I cannot move my text layers around because I get the pop up telling me it cannot complete my request because the layer is locked.

I did not put a lock on the layer.

I'm stumped as to what is happening. How do I go about fixing this problem.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your layers panel looks like?

Comment: This question does not really provide enough info to be solved. Its like asking: "my car wont start whats wrong with it?". You may wish to edit this. Closing for now.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text layer

Look at the top of your Layers-Panel. There are multiple locks displayed.

Make sure none of them is activated

You cannot deactivatd them?
Make sure, that the text layer isn't inside a locked group.
Groups can be locked and their effect also appliew on the layers inside of the group.

Move the laye out of the group or unlock the group to unlock your layer

in the layer panel and make sure that none of of lixks are applied

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean it's your issue but:

A lot of time, when magical things happen when they shouldn't, it's because you're using a keyboard shortcuts you are not aware of.

It's possible you are pressing the "/" while being on your layer and it will lock it or its transparency.

You can lock/unlock layers with this keyboard shortcut.

[image: numeral keyboard with lock unlock layers in Photoshop]